# Linking the objective c class files through terminal without using Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, terminal

I am finding so many answers to compile an objective c file in terminal, where as I need to know how to link all of them how to bundle it and then run it as an application through terminal?

**Note:** I am just trying to do  one app without Xcode, but I am using Xcode for my other    projects and I am a big fan of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /projectFilePath
xcodebuild -target "projectName" -configuration Release
```

It will create `/projectFilePath/build/Release/projectName.app` take a look at [XCODEBUILD Manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html).

Comment: I already used this command, I don want to use any Xcode related command, i am sure there is an alternate to do this just no luck finding it:)